# python zlib - size of compressed string vs Shannon entropy

Tags: python, string, compression, zlib, information-theory

I am trying to better understand how the output of compression algorithms - such as zlib - compares with one's theoretical expectation. So I have a couple of questions.

(1) First I'd like to check that I am correctly computing the compression ratio. Say I want to compress an array of 1000 ones, I can do the following

```
# encode the array such that len(s) == 1000 bytes
s = np.ones(1000, dtype='uint8').tostring()

# compress using the python zlib (deflate)
comp_s = zlib.compress(s, 9) 
# giving comp_s = 'x\xdacd\x1c\x05\xa3`\x14\x0cw\x00\x00\xa7e\x03\xe9'

comp_ratio = len(comp_s)/len(s)
# giving 17/1000
```

Hence my first question: is `comp_s` encoded such that its length corresponds to the number of bytes? I couldn't quite figure out how this string is encoded. If I do `sys.getsizeof(comp_s)` I find that it's size 54 bytes instead of 17 bytes? Since `getsizeof` returns the size of the python object so it certainly overestimates the size of the string, am I correct assuming that `sys.getsizeof(s) - sys.getsizeof('')` is the correct way? It seems to yield the same result as `len()` at least.

(2) The size of a compressed sequence should be greater than (or equal to) its Shannon entropy. For a random binary sequence of 1's and 0's occurring with 50:50 probability, the number of information per digit is 1-bit (by definition `h = - p log p - (1-p)log(1-p)`). Since a truly random sequence is incompressible, if I generate a random binary sequence of length `n` I would expect that by adding one random digit, the resulting `n+1` long sequence will be on average 1-bit larger after compression.

When I do the following

```
rawsize = range(1, 100000, 1000)
compsize = []
for l in rawsize:
    s = np.random.randint(0, 2, l, dtype='uint8').tostring() 
    comp_s = zlib.compress(s, 9)
    # note: I compress again to achieve better compression when l is large
    comp_s = zlib.compress(comp_s, 9)
    compsize.append(len(comp_s))
```

If I plot `compsize / rawsize` I find that the curve approaches a constant value around `0.155` meaning (if I interpret correctly) that by adding one digit the amount of information increases by `0.155`-bits. I do not understand this, as it seems that the compression is doing much better than the theoretical expectation.

To understand this further I also compared the compressed string size for the case of binary sequences of 1's and 0's where the 1's occur with probability `0<p<1`. Then, the compressed size of the string (per digit) should trace the Shannon entropy and be maximal `(=1)` at `p=0.5`. I find that the curve for the compressed string size (per digit) lies far below the Shannon entropy and that if I multiply the Shannon entropy by `0.155` they roughly lie on top of each other.

Clearly there is some normalisation factor I am not accounting for, but I can't figure out the rationale for it. I have also tried to encode the original sequence using `16`, `32` and `64` bits unsigned integers and found that the ratio `compsize / rawsize` becomes roughly `0.176`, `0.2`, `0.23`, respectively, so it looks like that by adding one byte in the representation of 1's and 0's we contribute about `0.25` bits of extra information, this is also curious.

Any suggestion would be really useful!

Comment: I put this as a note for the `1` bit longer claim, that as you stated correctly that would be for truly random sequences, which is not the common case.

Comment: zlib introduces 6 bytes of overhead, and deflate adds several more.  When you double-compress, you'll get the overhead bytes included twice.

Comment: the overhead is insignificant (max 0.03% according to documentation). The problem that I am reporting is that I seem to be compressing far more efficiently than I should be able to -- about 6 times. As a sidenote, I have tried to do the same with `np.random.bytes(N)` and `compsize / rawsize` approaches `1` in that case, maybe it gives some useful hint to what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

When calling `np.random.randint(0, 2, l, dtype='uint8').tostring()`, you are not obtaining a random sequence of 0 and 1, but a random sequence of *the 8-bit binary representations* of 0s and 1s: `10000000` and `00000000`. Pretty much 1 every 8 bits is random, the other 7 are all 0s. I guess the optimal ratio should be about 1/8, plus some overhead.

Indeed, if using `np.random.randint(0, 256, 100000, dtype='uint8').tostring()` instead, the comp_ratio is ~1.

Comment: thank you, that's what I concluded as well when I figured that the ratio is roughly `log2(k)/8`, where k is the dictionary size (largest integer in this case, for k=256 then I get 1). So would the right thing to do be taking a sequence `s1` of 1s and 0s of length N and convert each block of 8 to the corresponding integer, obtaining a sequence `s2` of length N/8? Then by compressing `s2`, zlib should try to compress a bit-array corresponding to `s1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are finding that when you add one bit of entropy to the input, you are adding 0.155 *bytes* to the compressed output, which is 1.24 *bits*.